# Filling html form by data form json using FormData

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Below snippet show how to convert form data to json in easy way using `FormData` (form in my real case have not 2 but about 40 fields)

```js
function readForm(e,form) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(form);
  let json = JSON.stringify([...data.entries()]);
  console.log(json);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="John">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc" value="123456">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!" onclick="readForm(event,myForm)">
</form>
```

but is there a way to perform reversed operation: fill html form on screen with data from such json - in similar easy way (also using FormData or other system object, but without using external lib)? Or the only way to do it is read each input form element and fill it one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add values for inputs one by one, but it could be easier to be done dynamically...

ex:

```js
function readForm(e,form) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(form);
  let json = JSON.stringify([...data.entries()]);
  console.log(json);
  
  JSON.parse(json).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    form[key] && (form[key].value = value + " updated");
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="John">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc" value="123456">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!" onclick="readForm(event,myForm)">
</form>
```